# How to define two values type for one field with Pydantic

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I use Pydantic to validate value, it works perfectly but I want to authorize Date and Null type for my field `validated_at` like:

```
validated_at:Opt[Datetime], Opt[Null]
```

Is there a way to do it?

Currently my class look like this:

```
class Fdes(FdesCreate):
    """FDES Validation Schema for get requests"""
    id: PyObjectId = Field(default_factory=PyObjectId, alias="_id")
    created_at: Datetime 
    updated_at: Datetime
    validated_at:Opt[Datetime]
    archived_at: Opt[Datetime]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what `Opt`, `Datetime`, and `FdesCreate` are, however, you can simply use [`Optional`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional) in the model definition, e.g.:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional

class SomeModel(BaseModel):
    validated_at: Optional[datetime]

s = SomeModel()
print(s)
# validated_at=None

s = SomeModel(validated_at=datetime.now())                                      
print(s)
# validated_at=datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 6, 20, 25, 13, 173546)

s = SomeModel(validated_at="something_else")                                    
# raises ValidationError:
# pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for SomeModel
#validated_at
#  invalid datetime format (type=value_error.datetime)
```

Comment: `Opt` is for Optional and `Datetime` is for `datetime` `FdesCreate` is just a class
My goal is to have `validated_at: Optional[datetime], Optional[null]`

Comment: `Optional[datetime]` itself will assign null to `validate_at` if the passed value is not datetime. 

`Optional[datetime]` is same as `Union[datetime, None]`

Comment: @Howins - There is no `null` in Python. If you mean `None` then `Optional[datetime]` is probably what you need, it will allow either a `datetime` or `None`. If that's not what you want, then maybe you could clarify what you would like to achieve?